# Image pixels not equal size opencv/C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm attempting to use opencv2 to preprocess and display images for classification but the pixels do not seem to be formatting properly, I'm not sure if formatting is the proper term. The image was originally 1080p and I used ffmpeg to crop and scale to 480X800. I was getting weird results so testing the program using the following code to overlay a simple checkerboard pattern where all squares should be the same size and square -

```
std::string image_path = samples::findFile("/home/pi/test.jpg");
Mat img = imread(image_path, IMREAD_COLOR);
cv::cvtColor(img, img, COLOR_BGR2RGB);
for (int i = 0; i < 15 ; i++ ) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 25 ; j++ ) {
     int x;
     if ((i + j) % 2 == 0) x = 1;
     else x = 0;
     for (int a = i * 32; a < (i + 1) * 32 ; a++) {
       for (int b = j * 32; b < (j + 1) * 32 ; b++) {
         img.at<int>(a, b) = x * img.at<int>(a, b);
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

I get the following

[checkerboard_test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNAve.jpg)

the original image looks exactly like it should without any stretching or other issues. This is being displayed on a small touch screen attached to a raspberry pi. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, code should be -

```
img.at<Vec3b>(a, b) = x * img.at<Vec3b>(a, b);
```

instead of

```
img.at<int>(a, b) = x * img.at<int>(a, b);
```